# PHP require/include. Permission denied

Tags: php, include

So I'm trying to include all folder files. It's including index.html first because it's in there. (I'm not including the file manually because there is styles folder in 'default' folder and it wont be included if I will include like "include('themes/default/index.html'); ").
So this is how I'm icluding

```
include("themes/default/");
```

And I get two errors:

**Warning: include(C:\wamp\www\project\themes\default): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\project\index.php on line 39**

And

**Warning: include(): Failed opening 'themes/default/' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\project\index.php on line 39**

I use Wamp on Windows 8.1 Pro. I set all fodlers, all files permissions to full access.

So, when I include index.php (or html) file, page looks like this http://postimg.org/image/xfyfdv78f/ but it should look like this one http://postimg.org/image/9pqw3dsg9/ .

Comment: You're attempting to include a directory?

Comment: That does not work the way you do it. But assuming it would work somehow: What is in that directory, and how should it be "all included"? Especially: In which order should the files be included? Sorted alphabetically, numerically, by last modified date, random? Please add some more info about what you have as a basis (i.e. examples of files), and what the result should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is looking for a file and getting an error when it can not read it.  If you want to include more than one file and maybe some unknown at the time files you can accomplish this in a better way.

If you are using OOP and classes for your application you can create a class and autoload in includes as they are needed.
You can read more on autoloading at PHP.net.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

This example here is a little better way to explain this.
http://www.codeforest.net/autoload-your-classes-in-php

Comment: I made that function and it throws me an error.

Comment: ... and the error would be?

Comment: Version of PHP would help too when you are trying to describe what you are doing.

Comment: PHP Version 5.5.12.
I get the same two errors as i did and  the one that should be thrown in the __autoload function.  Unable to open a file.

Comment: Are you programming using OOP and classes?  This is a method if using OOP classes.  You didn't really provide any code so I wasn't sure if you were using classes or not.

Comment: I understand OOP but I didn't use classes. I just wrote that function and called it. http://pastebin.com/Bimm57S4

Comment: First of all: If you have code, it has to be in your question above, not on pastebin. Second: You are doing it wrong. `__autoload()` should only be used to load the code for classes, but should also NOT be used because the correct way is to use `spl_autoload_register()`. If you don't want to autoload the code for your own classes, don't use it.

Answer (score 2):

Add the full path in. You are requesting a folder and not a file. Its not apache and doesn't know it should "try" and include a file called index.html

Comment: So, should I include it like this?  include("themes/default/index.html");

Comment: If you want them all read the directory and then loop though including the files. But yes that syntax is correct

Comment: This is what page looks when I'm including index.html. http://postimg.org/image/xfyfdv78f/ . And this is how it should look like http://postimg.org/image/9pqw3dsg9/ .

Comment: @exussum I fail to see how "adding the full path" would help in any way with including a directory, if I assume you mean "add the full path to the directory".

Comment: Sven the path is /dir/file and not /dir/ which is what the op is doing

Comment: The current code is `include("themes/default/")`, which is a relative path. "Adding the full path" is likely to mean `include("/srv/www/htdocs/public/themes/default/")`.

Comment: @sven sorry -  should have been more clear full path meaning the path to the file not from /

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to include all folder files

You'll have to write your own code for that. PHP does not have any built-in function to do ìt.

Whatever, I recommend you reconsider the whole approach. Almost all assets (JavaScript, CSS, pictures...) will just not work if you inject them right in the middle of your HTML.

Comment: Well, it's not including all files, but it sees all files. All files in css folder, all files in js folder. And if I will include index.html file, PHP will not see those files in those fodlers and it wont load. I tried it and i got no styles on my site.

Comment: What do you mean with "see files"? Do you want to fetch the directory listing generated automatically by Apache?

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to include a directory when include() only works on files. Per the answer from @exussum it's loading the page correctly, but the issue is most likely with the HTML not having correct paths. When you include a file via PHP all of your paths must be from your PHP file and not the HTML file. Use Chrome's developer tools if you can and you'll most likely see 404 errors.